# Publishing Google Sheet Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, chrome-web-store

I have recently mane add-on for Google Sheet. I want to publish as Add-On. However it doesn't seems to be possible. I follow `Publish` -> `Deeploy as Seets add-ons` and Publish (Instruction here https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons).

However, when I open new sheet then search my add-ons (`Add-ons` -> `Get add-ons`), I can not find. My add-ons has published status on `Chrome Web Store` -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/powrbot/kaeakcajahjjdgamodmdbinnpimkhkhp/related?authuser=1.

Also oAuth consent is approved by Google.